# Thank goodness I was working from home

Tags: phrase-usage

> First I burst into uncontrollable tears. Then I stood and began to frantically shake my arms. **Thank goodness I was working from home**; if my colleagues had seen me, who knows what they would have thought. I wasn’t sure what I thought myself.
> Source: [Science](https://www.science.org/content/article/i-felt-overwhelmed-new-professor-until-i-hired-personal-coach)

"Thank goodness" sounds to be properly said by a woman but not for a man to me. Is there a phrase better said by a man with similar meaning but without religious tints (phrases like "Thank God" or "Good Heavens" are too religious to apply when we want it sound neutral)?

Comment: "*"Thank goodness" sounds to be properly said by a woman but not for a man to me.*" ... why?

Comment: The word "goodness sounds a bit feministic to me.

Comment: I ask you again: [Why?](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/goodness)

Comment: The literature I read in the past gave me the impression. And I need native speakers to confirm and recommend.    Mind you: threads are meant for answering, not keeping asking.

Comment: Do you mean feminine or feminist?  It has nothing to do with ideology or politics (except insofar as it's a euphemism for "God") - the use of "goodness!" as an exclamation goes back to at least the 1600s and "thank goodness" at least the early 1800s.  It's not gender-specific, though it's possible that men are (or have traditionally been) less likely to use euphemisms than women (some studies support that).  For non-religious alternatives to "thank God" (although many non-religious people use it) see also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/321750/252981

Comment: @NewPlanet -if by "threads" you mean the comments (where this is) then the purpose of them is to ask questions to get the original poster (i.e. you) to clarify their question.  Comments are not meant for answers. They are exactly for 'keeping asking'.

Comment: @Skye-AT probably the OP was influenced by the fact the author of the piece is a woman. And probably the term the OP meant to say was *effeminate* or *unmanly*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA HA! that made me laugh. thanks for (possible) explanation.

Comment: In some languages, like Korean, there are distinct patterns of speech for men and women, and speakers of those languages tend to analyze English to see which expressions feel feminine or masculine, even though they don't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Goodness!" and "thank goodness" can be used by men as well as women.

I believe "Goodness!" originated as a euphemism for "God!".  "Thank God!" doesn't seem blasphemous, but perhaps some people might consider it to be so if used in trivial contexts (I have never known anyone to consider "Thank God!" the least bit offensive, but the alternatives such as "Thank goodness!" were coined centuries ago). Whatever the original justification, "Thank goodness!" also feels like a softer or euphemistic version of "Thank God!".  Sociologically, some groups of people are more likely to use euphemisms than others.  This might vary by social class, region, gender, age - and also the setting in which you find yourself.

As these expressions might be seen as weaker or euphemistic alternatives to "God!" and "thank God", they may be looked down on in *some* social settings.  In some social settings, exclaiming the F-word will cause offence, whereas if you are a 17-year-old male and you say "oh, fudge" at a party where you are among friends and there are no adults around, people might actually mock you.  (This is called inverse prestige.  So if you are in an upper-class setting then it is prestigious to use Received Pronunciation, whereas if you are in an informal working-class setting and want to be accepted as a full member of the 'in' group, it might even be advisable to avoid RP - although of course if you are an RP speaker and you are seen as trying to adopt a different accent, that could be much worse because you might come across as mocking them through failed imitation.)

For example, if you are a member of a social group in which it is customary to swear a lot and you are talking among yourselves, it is at least possible that your peers will make fun of you if you say "thank goodness" and almost certain if you say "goodness gracious" or "oh, deary me".

You could use "what a relief!", "what a relief that I was working from home!" or "thankfully, I was working from home".

Note: "Thank God!" is a common expression and does not imply that you are religious.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing particularly female-oriented or feminine about "Thank goodness" or indeed "Thank God": men as well as women use those phrases all the time, and no one thinks it odd.

It is true that "Thank goodness" arose as a variant of "Thank God". It no longer carries any clear indication of religious belief -- I have heard people say things similar to "Thank god I am an atheist" without any ironic intent.

I have known a few people who felt that saying "Thank God" outside of a formal prayer was religiously wrong, but such people are now quite rare in my experience. It may be that "Thank goodness" arose when such beliefs were more common, as a form of [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath).

If one wants to avoid even a slight suggestion of religious intent one might say"

> - I am so glad that X
> - It was so lucky that X
> - It was very fortunate  that X
> - It was a good thing that X

None of these is particularly used by men or women, by the way.

As the answer by rjpond indicates, such phrases may be more appropriate in some social registers than others.